# Function parameters out of nowhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've just begun to work with NodeJS and I find myself puzzled on code such as

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    // req and res are objects
})
```

I often see these kinds of function calls where the parameters in the anonymous function seem to come out of nowhere, yet contain various attributes and/or methods within?

Comment: `.get` is a function with two parameters, a path and a callback. The callback probably run in the code like so: `callback(request, response)`  - so when you pass in an anonymous method, you give it a `req, res` parameters. Read the API docs to see what parameters callbacks take.

Comment: Thing is, I don't define the req and res objects anywhere, i just pass them in and somehow they turn into objects with methods

Comment: Functions are first class data types. It's basically an object with special abilities. So you pass that function object to the internals of the `get` method, and when the time comes, it invokes that function. It has the `req` and `res` objects, and it *passes them* to your function.

Comment: You're not understanding callbacks, you will never define them anywhere, `express` defines them and passes them into the callback of `.get`

Comment: If you saw a named function declaration stading by itself like `function handleTransaction(req, res) { ... }`, you wouldn't think it was odd, would you? You'd just figure it gets called somewhere else in the code. Well, this is just like that; the code that calls the function is simply somewhere inside of `app.get`. It so happens that the way `app.get` chooses to call the function is to supply particular request and response objects as the function's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a function to another function, this

```
function(req, res) {
}
```

is a function. Assuming you gave it a local variable name like `b` in the called method, the function could then be invoked. As an example, -

```
app.get = function(a, b) { // <-- assign a function to app.get
  b("one", "two"); // <-- and then req would be one, and res would be two.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually found [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L544):

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

As you can see, `express()` is `this` and it is being used as a parameter to `createServer`.

You can find the documentation of [createServer here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener):

> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event.

Then when you check the `request` event [here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request):

**Event: 'request'**

```
function (request, response) { }
```

> Emitted each time there is a request. Note that there may be multiple
>   requests per connection (in the case of keep-alive connections).
>   request is an instance of http.IncomingMessage and response is an
>   instance of http.ServerResponse.

Technically this event gets emitted every time a new request from a browser is received.

And this code

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    // req and res are objects
})
```

Is somewhat a listener for a request to this route ([check expressjs source code](https://github.com/strongloop/express/tree/master/lib)).

So `req` and `res` are short-hand of `request` and `response` and are passed from the `request` event.

Then express added some more methods/properties found [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/request.js) and [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js).

---

If you want to see the code for `.get()`, see [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L153).